# Does 数独{すうどく} really mean "single number"?

Tags: meaning, compounds

I've never actually played a sudoku puzzle (I know, I live in a cave!).

I just saw the word written in kanji somewhere, which rekindled my interest.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) states:

> The puzzle was popularized in 1986 by the Japanese puzzle company
>   Nikoli, under the name Sudoku, meaning single number.

Though to me, the compound 数独{すうどく} implies "number addiction", especially in the context of a game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that sudoku exists as an actual word. Literally it does mean "single number," as it is a combination of the characters for "number" and "single." However the mathematical term for singular (versus plural) is 単数{たんすう}.

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%B0%E7%8B%AC) for it, the name is a reduction of the phrase "数字は独身に限る," or basically "limited to one number." I don't know if there are any hidden puns about number puzzle enthusiasts being forever alone, but a subsequent publication of this type of puzzle in Japan shortened that title to 数独, and thus it was named.

Comment: +1 for the puns which should exists ;) (and of course the great answer!)